# DHCP and IP address acquired event

Tags: linux, networking, linux-device-driver, network-protocols

I am using Linux and I need some indication that an IP address has been acquired by the n/w interface over DHCP. Is there any event that I can wait for... Ideally I would like to have something like this: An event or a call back so that whenever the interface acquires an IP address I can get to know immediately. Is there any such event or call back or any provision?

Thanks!

Comment: Each time  a new DHCP address is allocated in Linux there will be a corresponding entry in the system logs. /var/log/syslog might be  a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a desktop distro running NetworkManager, it will run scripts in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d when the network interface changes state, passing information via the command line and environment variables.  I forget the details, but you can check the documentation and existing examples.

NetworkManager also has a dbus interface, which you can listen to for the same information.  Running (as root) `dbus-monitor --system` while you bounce your interface will show you the relevant signal.

Comment: Can you help me with integrating this in a script - I would like to know how I can add code in my script to know that ethernet interface has got an IP address.